# import a file from root directory to subdirectory - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, relative-import

This is my directory structure

```
├───coreyTutorials
   ├───test
   |   ├───test_calc.py
   │   ├───__init__.py
   ├───calc.py
   └───__init__.py
```

I want to import `calc.py` in `test_calc.py`. But not successful

I've tried the below:

1. `import calc`  => ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calc'
2. `from .. import calc`  => ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Does `from calc import calc` work?

Comment: How did you run the test `test_calc.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add project directory as your path and then you can import your custom library.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/project-absolute-directory")
import calc
```